# Linq to Entities - GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to order a bunch of record by a Guid (most used), then group by this column and take the top 3 most used Guids.

```
IList<Records> dbobjs = dbContext.Records
         .OrderByDescending(t => t.Id)
         .GroupBy(t => t.Id)
         .Take(3)
         .ToList();
```

This is not working... What am i doing wrong? Its saying:

> `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<System.Guid,DataAccessLayer.Records>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<DataAccessLayer.Records>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn’t an Id be unique? And therefore an `GroupBy` doesn’t make much sense or do I miss something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your query is returning groupings of records - whereas you're just trying to assign the query result to an `IList<Records>`. Are you then just interested in the first three actual records? If so, you could use:

```
IList<Records> dbobjs = dbContext.Records
         .OrderByDescending(t => t.Id)
         .GroupBy(t => t.Id)
         .SelectMany(group => group) // Flatten again
         .Take(3)
         .ToList();
```

... but at that point, it's not clear what the point of grouping is. If you want to select just *one* record with each ID, you could use:

```
IList<Records> dbobjs = dbContext.Records
         .OrderByDescending(t => t.Id)
         .GroupBy(t => t.Id)
         .Take(3)
         .Select(group => group.First())
         .ToList();
```

EDIT: If you only need the GUIDs, you'd use:

```
IList<Guid> guids = dbContext.Records
         .OrderByDescending(t => t.Id)
         .GroupBy(t => t.Id)
         .Take(3)
         .Select(group => group.Key)
         .ToList();
```

Comment: The "Id" column is all i need. So a IList<> containg 3 Guid's

Comment: @Nugs: If you only need the GUIDs, why are you trying to assign to an `IList<Records>`? Will edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet I used your second suggestion and I had the error: "The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead."

Answer (score 3):

As the error clearly states, `GroupBy` returns a set of groupings, not a set of records.

Comment: Ok, So how should this be cast so that i can get the top 3 Guid's?

Answer (score -1):

If you execute this than the result will not going to be IList.
Try this, you will see:

```
var dbobjs = dbContext.Records
         .OrderByDescending(t => t.Id)
         .GroupBy(t => t.Id)
         .Take(3)
         .ToList();
```

Move the cursur over the var keyword in Visual Studio. ;)